# Initializing variables in a class

Tags: java, c++, class

I'm studying computer engineering, my 2nd semester just began. I've been making Android applications for a few while.

My programming lecturer (teaches C++ (Object Oriented)) said we can't initialize variables in a class unless we use a constructor since there's no memory dedicated to those data members before making an object of that class.

He said this is incorrect:

```
class example
{
       int a = 0;
};
```

But my experience says something else:

I've made a class in my Android project that keeps my Constants. I don't make any objects of that class. I've initialized variables and never used a constructor. But it works fine:

```
public class Constants {

       public static final int a = 1;

}
```

I want to know how am I initializing variables when there's no memory dedicated to that variable and how it works.

What part of my story is wrong? I want to know how my code works when there's no memory dedicated to my variables (Constants)?

Comment: @Blob Do you mean java dedicates memory to variables in a class without making an object?

Comment: @Blob I just edited my question

Comment: Your instructor is teaching some outdated C++.

Answer (score 4):

#### The Truth

```
class A {
   int a = 0;
};
```

In-class initializers became legal in *C++11*; so the only conclusion to draw from what you have said is that your teacher is living in the past.

<sup>However, if he is teaching *C++03* and not a later revision of the language, he's correct about it being ill-formed.</sup>

---

It is important to note that what he said regarding (non-static) data-members and their lack of storage until an object of such class has actually been created still applies.

An in-class initializer will initialize the *data-member* during construction, as long as the *data-member* isn't initialized in the used constructor's *mem-initializer* (then the latter takes precedence).

```
struct A {
  A () = default;
  A (int x)   : m (x) { }
  int m = 0; // ^ mem-initializer
};
```

```
A x;       // `x.m` is initialized to `0`
A y (123); // `y.m` is initialized to `123`
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [**cppreference.com** - Non-static data members : **Member Initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization)

Answer (score 1):

> He said this is incorrect:
>
> ```
> class example
> {
>        int a = 0;
> }
> ```

Well, yes, it's incorrect, there needs to be a semicolon at the end, after the `}`.

With that semicolon, this is legal C++11; the `= 0` is a non-static data member initializer (NSDMI for short). It's syntatic sugar for performing the equivalent initialization in the constructor.

---

> ```
> public class Constants {
>
>        public static final int a = 1;
>
> }
> ```

`static` things are per-class, and exists even if no objects of that class is ever created. Non-static things are per-object.